# Safety of using pthreads in Gtk+2.0 application

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, pthreads

I have a simple multithreaded Gtk+2.0 application that acquires data from multiple sources (microphone, webcam, temperature sensor), and displays data from these as images on screen (webcam frame grabs, microphone data represented as oscilloscope renders, text, etc).

It's to my understanding from the Gtk manual [and various articles](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness) that only the main processing thread should use any Gtk functions/calls that affect the UI. However, the `main()` entry point blocks on `gtk_main()` until I close the UI. With the exception of event handlers that are mapped to things like when I click on a button or slider in my UI, it seems the only option left open to me is to spawn a few `pthread`s and have them do the periodic sampling of data and updating information on-screen in the UI.

I remember from doing some MFC GUI development a long ways back that a similar principle applied: only a single specific thread should be updating the UI elements. How do I accomplish this in C with Gtk+2.0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html), the main even loop can accept sources from different threads:

> A GMainContext can only be running in a single thread, but sources can
>   be added to it and removed from it from other threads.

So you can inject the code in the UI thread from your working thread by:

1. creating a `GSource` (e.g., by using [`g_idle_source_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-source-new));
2. adding the code you want to be executed with [`g-source-set-callback`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-set-callback);
3. attaching it to the UI thread context with [`g_source_attach()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-attach).

Here is a sample program for GTK+2 and GLib >= 2.32:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define N_THREADS    100
#define N_ITERATIONS 100

GtkWidget *bar;
GMainContext *context;

static gboolean
update_progress_bar(gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(bar),
                                  g_random_double_range(0, 1));
    return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
}


static gpointer
thread_func(gpointer user_data)
{
    int n_thread = GPOINTER_TO_INT(user_data);
    int n;
    GSource *source;

    g_print("Starting thread %d\n", n_thread);

    for (n = 0; n < N_ITERATIONS; ++n) {
        /* If you want to see anything you should add a delay
         * to let the main loop update the UI, e.g.:
         * g_usleep(g_random_int_range(1234, 567890));
         */
        source = g_idle_source_new();
        g_source_set_callback(source, update_progress_bar, NULL, NULL);
        g_source_attach(source, context);
        g_source_unref(source);
    }

    g_print("Ending thread %d\n", n_thread);
    return NULL;
}


gint
main(gint argc, gchar *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GThread *thread[N_THREADS];
    int n;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    bar = gtk_progress_bar_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), bar);

    context = g_main_context_default();

    for (n = 0; n < N_THREADS; ++n)
        thread[n] = g_thread_new(NULL, thread_func, GINT_TO_POINTER(n));

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    for (n = 0; n < N_THREADS; ++n)
        g_thread_join(thread[n]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to accomplish this with a simple GTK + pthreads setup? Thanks!

Comment: @Dogbert Just added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is the most in-line with what I meant with my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do your sampling in separate threads, as you suggest. The question then is how you update the UI. What I would do is to use a 'self-pipe'. This is normally done to communicate from signal handlers, but it works just fine between threads when one of the threads can't wait on a condition variable. What you do here is set up a dedicated pipe, write one character to the pipe in the thread that has got the data, and `select()` on the read end of the pipe in the main program's `select()` loop. Details here: [Using self-pipe, how can I avoid that the event loop stalls on read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872371/using-self-pipe-how-can-i-avoid-that-the-event-loop-stalls-on-read) - useful background on its origins [here](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html).

You can then make GTK+ listen on the read end of the pipe. Your problem is thus reduced to making GTK+ respond to something on an FD - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826523/gtk-main-and-unix-sockets) (first answer) for how.

Comment: I'm only familiar with GTK+ 3. Does GTK+ 2 not have a `gdk_threads_idle_add()`?

Comment: @andlabs I'm unaware of that (and Google seems mostly unaware of it too). I suppose I was answering a more general question of how to communicate between a thread and an event loop written for a traditional nonthreaded program.

Comment: The thing is, this doesn't quite address how the `main` thread is supposed to update the UI while it's blocked on the `gtk_main()` function. Is it ok for a separate thread to update the UI? I have all UI update calls wrapped with a mutex so no two threads attempt to update the UI simultaneously.

Comment: Does the second link above not explain that?

Comment: @abligh right; I was going to say that that function would be how you queued some code to run on the main thread when it's not doing anything (and thus would be how to communicate, except for synchronization). What you're describing in the answer seems a little messy for the sole purpose of updating a GUI, but I don't know GTK+ 2 so I can't really comment...